# How to sort the values and make interactive with mousehover?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have built the horizontal bar chart with code

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.4.json",
  "description": "Bar chart with text labels. Apply scale padding to make the frame cover the labels.",
  "data": {
      "values": [
      {"Metrics": "A1", "Percentage": 0.79},
      {"Metrics": "A2", "Percentage": 0.0399},
      {"Metrics": "A3", "Percentage": 0.9868},
      {"Metrics": "A4", "Percentage": 0.0536},
      {"Metrics": "A5", "Percentage": 0.9412},
      {"Metrics": "A6", "Percentage": 0.0536}
      ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "Metrics", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {"field": "Percentage", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"padding": 10}}
  },
  "layer": [{
    "mark": "bar"
  }, {
    "mark": {
      "type": "text",
      "align": "left",
      "baseline": "middle",
      "dx": 3
    },
    "encoding": {
      "text": {"field": "Percentage", "type": "quantitative"}
    }
  }]
}
```

I get the plot like
[image]

The bars are not in order
May I know how to sort the values and plot and is it possible to make mousehover and see the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sorting

You can add a sort attribute to `encoding.y`, set its value as `-x` (descending) and make it as below:

```
"encoding": {
  "y": {
    "field": "Metrics",
    "type": "nominal",
    "sort": "-x"
  },
```

For ascending values, set `sort` attribute to `x`

Docs: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/sort.html#sort-by-encoding

### Values on mousehover

You can add a `tooltip` subsection in `encoding` section and add multiple data attributes as below:

```
"tooltip": [
  {
    "field": "Metrics",
    "type": "nominal"
  }, {
    "field": "Percentage",
    "type": "quantitative"
  }
]
```

Docs: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/tooltip.html

### Updated encoding section

```
"encoding": {
  "y": {
    "field": "Metrics",
    "type": "nominal",
    "sort": "-x"
  },
  "x": {
    "field": "Percentage",
    "type": "quantitative",
    "scale": {"padding": 10}
  },
  "tooltip": [{
    "field": "Metrics",
    "type": "nominal"
  }, {
    "field": "Percentage",
    "type": "quantitative"
  }
  ]
}
```

[link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAEyUALJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnZL0AISRaABLFOYzAdzowzmOAA9rgpEziCIlMwEEcHEEATzNoJEE4MxwkNTUaBTJHNjNkAGso+iiAMy0kBCioNlJzLLN3T29KFXUkTBRUUGIIhk00AG1QAFk4TB0oCDQQPwBGGoAFOC0oOAV6sjg0AAZKAHYATgBfZW7e-sH0PzEJqZm5pAXlyiWAZnWtnZAevpoBob8bk+nZ+cXUFfWAA4AGyA7a7F5vQ6SL5nX5XJYAVhuwPBTz2rwOw0RsJ+Fz+AMkIzEaOe+3ewNx50u-2uyNRAF1tiBZkV4ok0KBgpyQNkaF41EMyZiaphgjg-iAFGwEAkIjV5FpMEN+M4QMy1Y1efzBIL0JNvtTFqoxRKhgBHBhIOZ0Oo0UgKqARP6gGJxBJkNAjJabZmYNhsQT6HAdUB8gVCjFvE3iyXS2UKeVo8O6oYGuH40Wxi1Wm31fQOzZM1TuYJTUMgZBaNJDJimdWPKs1rWmyVOVw1CI0MiGECRbLK1R1iBeBKS2VxSI1NSam7M1lsdmelsuZValN6kDpvGXGNm9CW636fP2xa+oubIA) to updated spec